# Alert controller not being presented even though condition is met (value is empty)

Tags: ios, swift

I've been having an issue with a personal app where certain users seem to be missing a profile picture when they sign up (String). I've added a check to make sure the string isn't empty when the user presses the "Next" button - basically check if the string is `""`, and if so, present an alert controller to remind them to choose a profile picture. If it's not empty, then segue to the next screen. This is the relevant code (for clarity, `var emailUserPicString = ""` is a global variable):

```
   emailUserPicString = url.absoluteString
    print("\n\n\npic:\(emailUserPicString)\n\n\n")

    if emailUserPicString == "" {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Profile Picture Error", message: "Don't forget to choose a profile picture!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(alert :UIAlertAction!) in
        })
        alertController.addAction(okAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    } else {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "emailToSetup", sender: nil)
    }
```

Now, when I test this solution, pressing the `Next` button doesn't do anything, and no alert is presented. I'd think it would be one or the other - if the string is empty, the alert controller would be shown, and if there's a value, `performSegue` would happen and we'd be taken to the next screen. I'm wondering why neither of these are happening

This is the complete function if it can provide some context:

```
@IBAction func emailSignupNextPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    // Make sure text fields aren't empty
    guard nameField.text != "", emailField.text != "", passwordField.text != "", confirmPasswordField.text != "" else {return}

    if passwordField.text == confirmPasswordField.text {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            if let user = user {

                guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}

                // Use name as Firebase display name for readability
                let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser!.createProfileChangeRequest()
                changeRequest.displayName = self.nameField.text!
                changeRequest.commitChanges(completion: nil)

                // Create child node from userStorage "users". Profile image set to user's unique ID
                let imageRef = self.userStorage.child("\(uid).jpg")
                let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.selectProfileImageView.image!, 0.5)

                // Upload image to Firebase
                let uploadTask = imageRef.putData(data!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, err) in
                    if err != nil {
                        print(err!.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    imageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, er) in
                        if er != nil {
                            print(er?.localizedDescription as Any)
                        }
                        if let url = url {

                            emailUserPicString = url.absoluteString
                            print("\n\n\npic:\(emailUserPicString)\n\n\n")

                            if emailUserPicString == "" {
                                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Profile Picture Error", message: "Don't forget to choose a profile picture!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(alert :UIAlertAction!) in
                                })
                                alertController.addAction(okAction)

                                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                                return
                            } else {
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "emailToSetup", sender: nil)
                            }
                        }
                    })
                })
                uploadTask.resume()
            }
        })
    } else {
        //            print("Passwords don't match")
        passwordAlert()
    }
}
```

My question is, am I handling the string check correctly? If there's no value there, why is my alert controller not presenting? And if there is a value why is the segue not being performed?

Comment: What about the guard at the start? We exit entirely if that fails, so nothing happens.

Comment: Anyway, you have a debugger. Just walk thru the code as it runs and see what the issue is. No need to guess.

Comment: The guard simply checks to make sure the fields aren't empty - in testing, I've made sure that I fill out all the fields, so I know they're not empty.

Comment: Using the debugger will also verify that this code is triggered by the button.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you are presenting the `UIAlertAction` in a background Thread. So, you should present it in the UI Thread using:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  // show alert here
}
```

Comment: So I tried this, and I still didn't get the alert, but my print statement `print("\n\n\npic:\(emailUserPicString)\n\n\n")` is showing that the `emailUserPicString` is indeed empty, so the alert should be showing.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your if statement to

```
if emailUserPicString.isEmpty || emailUserPicString.isEmpty == ""{

}
```

Maybe an empty textField don't has a `== ""` String

Answer (score -1):

Follow this solution:

```
private func validateForm() {

    if emailTextField.text?.isEmpty {
        // Show alert message like: Please enter the email addess.
        return
    }

    if passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty && passwordTextField.text?.count < 6 {
        // Show alert message like: Password must be at least 6 chars long.
        return
    }

    if profleImage.image == nil {
        // Show alert message like: Please choose your profile photo.
        return
    }

    // Now you can post API request after validating all values.
    // Call here API request method.....
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Clearly explain (in the answer, not in comments) what was wrong and how the answer fixes the problem.